# How to download a file without save/open dialogue box programmatically?

Tags: java, file, csv, download, export

I am using below code to only download CSV file to local system but problem is it is showing save/open dialogue box which is not meeting my requirement.
Can any body please tell me how can i download a file without that dialogue box?

I don't need to configure my browser for that.

```
response.setContentType("application/csv; charset="+UINavigatorUtil.getFileEncoding(context, request);
response.setHeader( "Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName() + "\"" );
```

EDIT: I have one export button. I don't want to user to choose download location. It should get downloaded at common configured location.

Thanks!

Comment: **You can't.**
You can not save a file to the system without a user's consent. Imagine the security issues that would cause. *"I'm a evil scriptkiddy, let's fill up my poor victim's hard drive with junk files!"* (A completely filled hard drive makes your system very unstable, or even unable to boot)

Comment: Well, you can if you're a nefarious hacker and exploiting some security hole in a browser ...

Comment: @BrianRoach: Well, yea, but this ain't hackoverflow.com :P

Comment: JavaGuy, You say you want to save the file to a common configured location. What if the user uses a mac or linux pc? What if he's on a smartphone? What if the user has no file management rights at the desired target location?

I'm sorry, but what you want is **not possible.**

Comment: My application is windows based. I am thinking to comment second line and will call java method to write file contents to hard drive. Will it work?

Answer (score 0):

What is your requirement? If you plan to open the document in the browser (provided an appropriate plugin is configured) then set the content disposition as inline.

```
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=somefile.ext")
```

If you want to directly save the file then [as suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23236601/how-to-download-a-file-without-save-open-dialogue-box-programmatically#comment35551991_23236601) by @[Cerbrus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1835379/cerbrus) you can't.

Comment: 1: You misspelled my name. ;-) 2: OP is already using a `"Content-Disposition"` header.